# OpenGL where to process vertices

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, transformation, vertex-shader

I want to use Java and OpenGL (through LWJGL) to render a 3D object. I also use GLFW to set up windows, contexts, etc.

I have a custom class to represent a unit sphere, which stores coordinates of every vertex as well as an array of integers to represent the triangle mesh. It also stores the translation, scale factor and rotation (so that any sphere can be built from the unit sphere model).

The vertices are world coordinates e.g. (1, 0, 0) with s.f. as 5, translation (0, 10, 0) and rotation (0,0,0).

I also have a custom camera object which stores the position of the camera and the orientation (in radians) to each axis (yaw, roll, pitch). It also stores the distance to the projection plane to allow a changeable FOV.

I know that in order to display the sphere, I need to apply a series of transformations to all vertices. My question is, where should I apply each transformation?

OpenGL screen coordinates range from (-1,-1) to (1, 1).

My current solution (which I would like to verify is optimal) is as follows:

In CPU:

- Apply model transform on the sphere (so some vertex is now [5, 10, 0]). My model transform is in the following order: scale, rotation [z,y,x] then translation. Buffer these into vbo/vao and load into shader along with camera position, rotation and distance to PP.

In vertex shader:

- apply camera transform on world coordinates (build the transformation matrix here or load it in from CPU too?)
- calculate 2D screen coordinates by similar triangles
- calculate OpenGL coordinates by ratios of screen resolution
- pass resulting vertex coordinates into the fragment shader

Have I understood the process correctly? Should I rearrange any processes? I am reading guides online but they aren't always specific enough - most already store the vertices (in Java) in the OpenGL coordinate system but not world coordinates like me. Some say that the camera is fixed at the origin in OpenGL, though I assume that I need to apply the camera transform for it to be so and display shapes properly.

Thanks

Comment: If you already apply the camera transformation in the shader, it makes sense to also do the moder transformation there. pass `cameraMatrix * modelMatrix ` instead of only the camera matrix and everything should work. You might want to search for MVP matrix (model-view-projection).

Comment: @BDL so I should apply all transformations within the shader? So load in only vertex position and MVP matrix? Any benefits to using the CPU over the shader so compute data? If I have a lot of vertices, wouldn't the GPU be overburdened>

Comment: The gpu is way faster for this kind of operations. If your gpu is too slow to do the transformations, then your CPU is for sure to slow too. Also note, that you have the same amount of work in the shader when you multiply with view and model compared to just model.